# Change Storyboard when switching to Landscape

Tags: xcode, ipad, orientation

is there a Way to change the Storyboard when the user switch to Landscape to Portrait mode in the AppDelegate.m file I made it already to switch to different StoryBoards for different iOSs but I cant switch from Landscape to Portrait mode I already builded a Storyboard called `iPadios5landscape` and I am switching to the Storyboard with this Method `mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadios5landscape" bundle:nil];` But I don't know the way to detect the Orientation. And it is important to place it in this code

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")==NO)
    {

            if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
            {

                mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone_ios5" bundle:nil];
            }

            if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 1024)
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == 0) //Default orientation
        //UI is in Default (Portrait) -- this is really a just a failsafe.
        mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad_ios5" bundle:nil];

        else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
            //Do something if the orientation is in Portrait
            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad_ios5" bundle:nil];

            else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
                // Do something if Left
                mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadios5landscape" bundle:nil];

                else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
                    //Do something if right
                    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadios5landscape" bundle:nil];

                    }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Stick this in there to detect orientation, then set the storyboard if `deviceOrientation` is landscape or portrait

```
 UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if(orientation == 0) //Default orientation 
    //UI is in Default (Portrait) -- this is really a just a failsafe. 
 else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    //Do something if the orientation is in Portrait
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    // Do something if Left
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    //Do something if right
```

Comment: I used your code and mixed it up with my code check it out in my question most.